# c# - How I make Downloading exe file greater than 15 Kb

Tags: c#, download, exe, webclient

I want to Download exe file with c# form application.But it is Downloding only 15kb parts of exe:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("http://www.inndir.com/Bandizip-50255i.html", "myfile.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set it in the configuration file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024"/>
```

The above will limit the size to 1MB but you can set another value there.

Comment: That setting is related to uploads, not downloads.

Comment: can I make max lenght 4096kb? configuration file. Where I write this code? configuration file?

Comment: depending what kind of app it is? Is it ASP.NET WebForms, WinForms, ASP.NET MVC or something different?

Comment: winform application @bejger

Comment: I need to help so urgent please @Matthew

Comment: You should place it in your app.config file.

Comment: @akdrmrk I've checked your link,what's actually happening is that your app is not downloading any .exe file,instead it's downloading the web page which is about 14 KB in size.To download a file you'll need a direct link to it.To justify my comment open the file downloaded by your app in Notepad,look at the Notepad window and in no time you'll realize it's not an exe,but it's a HTML document.

Comment: @akdrmrk Your app is downloading [this](http://www.inndir.com/Bandizip-50255i.html) document and saving it as "myfile.exe".

Comment: Ok. how I find direct link for download can you send me a link @PurplrXenon